# How get AWS region name (e.g. US East (N. Virginia)) in python for RDS using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

My set of code is :

```
import boto3
rds = boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=reg_name)
client = boto3.client("rds",
                      aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
                      aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)
response = client.describe_source_regions()['SourceRegions']
print response
```

As output I am getting:

```
[{u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https: //rds.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'ap-northeast-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'ap-northeast-2'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-2'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'eu-central-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'eu-west-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'eu-west-2'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'sa-east-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'us-east-1'},
 {u'Status': 'available',
  u'Endpoint': 'https:// rds.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  u'RegionName': 'us-west-2'}]
```

but with region e.g. us-east-1 I also need its region name, i.e. US East (N. Virginia).

Answer (score 1):

In boto3, the region_name is the region-id, there is no exact region name description.  If you want the actual region description, you need to create your own mapping yourself as shown here : [AWS region name and region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#rds_region).

Comment: can't we gaet it programatically, what if new regions were added, then we have to manually go and change the list from where we are mapping??

Comment: There are "regions" that are outside typical user reach. I.e. AWS gov service and its China server.

Answer (score 0):

From CLI you can use the command `get-regions` which returns the `displayName` in the output, I don't know whether boto3 have the API to get the displayName.

Comment: It's part of the Lightsail commands. So you need to run: `aws lightsail get-regions`.

Comment: Currently AWS lightsail only available in some specific region, so you won't get the all the display name.